# GitHub ERROR: Repository not found. fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github, terminal

I'm trying to follow along Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails tutorial http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/beginning#fnref:1.16, but I've run across an error. I signed up on GitHub and issued a new SSH key and made a new repository. But when I try to push  my repository up to GitHub I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Any ideas?

Here are some of the commands I entered into the terminal:

```
Parkers-MacBook-Pro:.ssh ppreyer$ git remote add origin git@github.com:ppreyer/first_app.git
Parkers-MacBook-Pro:.ssh ppreyer$ git push -u origin master
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly – ppreyer 6 mins ago
```

And here is what `git remote -v` shows:

```
Parkers-MacBook-Pro:.ssh ppreyer$ git remote -v
github    git@github.com:ppreyer/first_app.git (fetch)
github    git@github.com:ppreyer/first_app.git (push)
origin    git@github.com:ppreyer/first_app.git (fetch)
origin    git@github.com:ppreyer/first_app.git (push)
```

Comment: What's your repository?  Exactly how are you trying to push?  What does `git remote -v` show?  Show us the exact commands you type and the exact output that is produced.

Comment: What about network environment?  Are you on a corporate or university network and thus perhaps behind a proxy server?

Comment: Nah, he's successfully contacting github.  The "`ERROR: Repository not found`" error comes from github.

Comment: The link is broken (404).

Answer (score 1):

Your repository was called "MyFirstRailsApp" but it appears you've deleted it.  That's the reason for your error.

Comment: But then I changed it to first_app. What do I do to get it to work?

Comment: Github says: "ppreyer doesn’t have any public repositories yet." You may think you renamed it on github, but you deleted it. The repository must exist on github before you can push to it.  Create a new "first_app" repository on github.